# ASW IAM Policy and Amazon API Gateway says two different thing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway, amazon-policy

I have policy: AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess
and user is associate with this policy but when I simulate action to invoke API it says access denied, can anyone help me understand what is the problem here??

Find simulator image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Jiy.png)

Answer (score 1):

The IAM policy simulator covers resource based permissions. Please make sure that you specify a resource ARN to test against since this is '*' by default (which doesn't work with API Gateway). You can enter the resource ARN by clicking on that service row.

Please use the following format for your resource ARN:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-1:YOUR-ACCOUNT:YOUR-REST-API-ID/YOUR-STAGE/GET/YOUR-RESOURCE-PATH
```

Hope this helps,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: I have Group "Admin" which is attached with existing policy "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" when I simulate this policy for user and group I have access denied as I mentioned in question, even after providing specific ARN.

Then I create New Policy with * for resource and attached to user and simulate "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" it shows allowed.

Is simulator simulate all the policies atteched to user?? or individual policy that we select during simulation?